# Django - navbar not showing properly while user logged in

Tags: html, django

I have a website with the following paths :

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
 path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
 path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='pages/login.html'), name='login'),
 path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='pages/logout.html'), name='logout'),
 path('mydata/', user_views.mydata, name="data"),
 path('', include('mysite.urls')),
]
```

each coding section in views directory is preceding by:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
[...]
@login_required
def profile(request):
[...]
@login_required
def mydata(request):
[...]
```

My problem is that I wish the **user to be able to only see 'profile' and 'logout', not 'login' or 'register'**, the logic works with every path, except for /mydata and I can't figure out why.

As for my HTML file the **base.html** looks like this:

```
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>             
              {% else %}
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
```

I include it in my **mydata.html** file like this:

```
{% extends "pages/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
[...]
{% endblock content %}
```

**My question is:** Is there any way to make sure the user is authenticated @ /mydata?

I am still relatively new, so your input is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's such a strange situation, I figured since I used @login_required beforehand, no logged off users could access this page anyways, hence why I decided to change my base.html file to:

```
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>             
      {% elif request.path == data %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>              
      {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
      {% endif %}
```

It all works good now! hope it helps someone else